# Given the x,y co-ordinates of n cities how to form the distance matrix using python?

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

I am new to programming, I was trying to solve a Travelling salesman problem where I was given x and y co ordinates of n different cities how to find the distance matrix using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your cities are placed on a plane - not on a globe - so you can use pure euclidean distance. And I also assume that you have your cities - e.g. input data in python dictionary like this:

```
cities = {
    "london": (4.15, 5.89),
    "paris": (2, 4),
    "prague": (1,5),
 }
```

Where the values enclosed in brackets are the corresponding coordinates.

Then, you will have to define function which computes the euclidean distance based on coordinates:

```
def distance_between(point_a, point_b):
    return math.sqrt((point_a[0] - point_b[0])**2 + (point_a[1] - point_b[1])**2)
```

You will also need a function that will produce the distance matrix based on your input. You will use the distance-computing function here:

```
def get_matrix(cities):
    distance_matrix = {}
    for city_a in cities:
        distance_matrix[city_a] = {}
        for city_b in cities:
            distance_matrix[city_a][city_b] = distance_between(
                    cities[city_a], cities[city_b])

return distance_matrix
```

Now you have everything sou you can use it like this:

```
distances = get_matrix(cities)
print(distances["london"]["london"])
print(distances["paris"]["prague"])
```

Output of this example are just two numbers:

```
0.0
1.4142135623730951
```

Also don't forget to place `import math` at the beginning of your .py file